# Entity framework code first migrations, sql user permissions?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

What is the minimal permission needed on a sql server user/login for it to be able to run entity framework code first database migrations?

I naively would have thought that a user with the roles db_datareader, db_datawriter, Grant Alter on the Schema and Grant Create Table would be permissive enough.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**On-Prem: SQL server with AD/sql login**

you need the following permissions on the database.

```
[db_datareader]
[db_datawriter]
[db_ddladmin]
```

For full control over database use

```
[db_owner]
```

**Azure Could: Azure SQL with ADD** (Edit)

Please add [dbmanager] to master and user database.

Comment: i receives error: "The specified schema name "{guid}@{guid2}" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it". I have created manually this schema and add persmission to ther user, but it still does not work.

Comment: Did you give permission to database or database schema?

Comment: I gave it all roles in database. Add add all permissions to schema.
ALTER ROLE db_accessadmin ADD MEMBER {name}
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER {name}
(...)
and 
GRANT ALTER, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, 
REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::"{schema name}" TO {name}

Comment: Schema name is {appId}@{AAD tenant id}. I authorize app in DB with MSI. Tutorial: https://www.azurecorner.com/using-managed-service-identity-in-azure-functions-to-access-azure-sql-database/

Comment: You are trying to connect to the azure sql with ADD? Is that right?

Comment: Add the user account to the dbmanager, the loginmanager role, or both in the master database using the ALTER SERVER ROLE statement (for Azure Synapse Analytics, use the sp_addrolemember statement).

Please follow this Microsoft document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins Please provide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213787/discussion-between-zolty13-and-hiten004).

Answer (score 5):

Clearly it depends on what your migrations are/(will be) doing. For my use case, I ended up creating a shema, and restricting the user that the migration uses to the permissions below.

```
GRANT ALTER, INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::schema_name TO migration_user
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO migration_user
```