# EF Code First Migration, performance issues when not using admin account in SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

We've built a web tool (C# WebAPI) to administrate migration of SQL Azure databases with Entity Framework Code First Migrations.

By default, when we create databases we also create logins and user accounts per database.

These accounts get db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions.

We use these accounts from the web app to connect to the database to get current migrations and if there are any pending migrations, apply them.

For some reason, this operation takes about 10 seconds every time (without applying any updates).

If we use the admin account (associated when setting up the sql server in Azure) instead the time drops to less than a second.

I've come to the conclusion that there must be some kind of permission thing that gives us the decrease of performance.

I've added db_ddladmin role explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830474/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-sql-user-permissions) without any success.

We use the DbMigrator class in Entity Framework Migrations to get pending migrations.

Comment: I dont think that may be the issue,can you try running the scripts again and see whats happening in database using `sys.dm_exec_requests` dmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation I found out that the solution to the problem is to create sql users in the master database also.

Before we only created logins and a corresponding user in the database.
According to this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2016/10/05/create-sql-login-and-sql-user-on-your-azure-sql-db/) SQL Azure doesn't support default database and therefore it defaults to the master database were I didn't have any rights.

Adding user to the master database solved the "performance" issue.